# How are labels dynamically placed on a line or polygon?

Tags: labeling

I was wondering if anyone knew the math involved, or resources for learning the math involved, in finding the ideal position, scale, and rotation of a label for a line or polygon on a map?

The most I've got so far is finding the centroid for a polygon (though it's not ideal for concave polygons).

Comment: I guess it is best to do this manually.

Comment: Related resource: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.54.8844 The Computational Complexity of Cartographic Label Placement. Citation includes other associated references.

Answer (score 2):

Centroid is never the answer but it is a good initial guess. The algorithms which are easiest to implement that solve similar problems usually operate by trying a few reproducible pseudo-random positions and scoring them somehow, keeping the best spots. For further reading I would start by reading up on bin packing algorithms and take it from there.

Answer (score 2):

A research paper that addresses this hard issue: 
http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=4015429

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [documentation of the PAL labeling library](http://pal.heig-vd.ch/index.php?page=support) is a good start for further research.
I especially recommend ["From Point Feature Label Placement to Map Labelling"](http://mistic.heig-vd.ch/taillard/articles.dir/mic09-115-Taillard_b.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Labeling is a nasty endeavor.

At a small scale: you have label overlap problems, so which one do you remove or should all be shown.

At a large scale: if you have a large polygon, where do you display the label.  Do you display it multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen maps where they just calculate a bounding box for a complex polygon and place the label in the center of that.

For simple lines, usually it's just the middle of the two endpoints.

I guess it really just depends on what you expect your data to be and how important the location of the label is.

Comment: What's up with the downvote? A comment might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the code in GeoTools and GeoServer if you grok java - it is a constantly evolving problem as people keep coming up with new corner cases that need fixing.